# C++ Maybe<T> implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, optional

In order to improve my understanding of C++ template meta-programming, SFINAE, references, and overall class design, I've tried to implement a `Maybe<T>` class in C++.

Of course, the class is heavily based off of Haskell's `Maybe` Monad, and has the same functionality. I am aware that `std::optional<T>` pretty much does the same thing in C++17, but I decided not to implement it exactly as the standard specifies.

In specific, I've renamed a few functions, and added some of my own (namely, the `apply` method). More notably, I tried to make it support possible references (by making it use a `std::reference_wrapper`).

Here is the code below:

maybe.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

namespace maybe {

struct nothing_t {} nothing;

template <typename T>
class Maybe_Base {

public:

    struct bad_access : std::exception {
        virtual const char* what() const noexcept {
            return "Attempted to access a value of a Maybe wrapper that doesn't exist.";
        }
    };


    Maybe_Base():
        val(nullptr)
    {}

    Maybe_Base(nothing_t):
        val(nullptr)
    {}

    template <class... Args>
    explicit Maybe_Base(Args&&... args) {
        val = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    ~Maybe_Base() {
        if (val)
            val->~T();
        delete val;
    }

    // Is there a way to ensure extraneous copies aren't made? Or is the only option just to delete the copy constructor entirely?
    Maybe_Base(const Maybe_Base<T>& other) {
        if (other.val)
            val = new T(*other.val);
        else
            val = nullptr;
    }

    Maybe_Base& operator=(Maybe_Base<T> other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    friend void swap(Maybe_Base<T>& a, Maybe_Base<T>& b) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.val, b.val);
    }

    Maybe_Base(Maybe_Base<T>&& other) {
        this->val = other.val;
        other.val = nullptr;
    }


    inline bool empty() const {
        return val == nullptr;
    }

    inline bool hasValue() const {
        return !empty();
    }

    inline explicit operator bool() const {
        return hasValue();
    }


    T value() {
        if (empty())
            throw bad_access();
        else
            return *val;
    }

    T valueOr(T defaultVal) {
        if (empty())
            return defaultVal;
        return *val;
    }

    const T& operator*() const {
        return *val;
    }
    T& operator*() {
        return *val;
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return val;
    }
    T* operator->() {
        return val;
    }


    void clear() {
        val->~T();
        delete val;

        val = nullptr;
    }

    template <class Func, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<    !std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Func, T, Args...>>
                      && !std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Func>,
        Maybe_Base<std::invoke_result_t<Func, T, Args...>>
    >
    apply(Func f, Args&&... args) {
        if (*this)
            return Maybe_Base<std::invoke_result_t<Func, T, Args...>>{f(this->value(), std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
        return nothing;
    }

    template <class Func, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<     std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Func, T, Args...>>
                      && !std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Func>,
        void
    >
    apply(Func f, Args&&... args) {
        if (*this)
            f(this->value(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class Pointer_To_Method, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<    !std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Pointer_To_Method, T, Args...>>
                      &&  std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Pointer_To_Method>,
        Maybe_Base<std::invoke_result_t<Pointer_To_Method, T, Args...>>
    >
    apply(Pointer_To_Method f, Args&&... args) {
        if (*this)
            return Maybe_Base<std::invoke_result_t<Pointer_To_Method, T, Args...>>{(this->value().*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
        return nothing;
    }

    template <class Pointer_To_Method, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<     std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Pointer_To_Method, T, Args...>>
                      &&  std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Pointer_To_Method>,
        void
    >
    apply(Pointer_To_Method f, Args&&... args) {
        if (*this)
            (this->value().*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    T* val;
};

template <class T, bool = std::is_reference_v<T>>
class Maybe;

template <class T>
class Maybe<T, false> : public Maybe_Base<T> {

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Maybe(Args&&... args): Maybe_Base<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <class T>
class Maybe<T, true> : public Maybe_Base<std::reference_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>>> {
    typedef std::reference_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>> Wrap_Type;
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Maybe(Args&&... args): Maybe_Base<Wrap_Type>(std::ref(args)...) {}

    T value() {
        return Maybe_Base<Wrap_Type>::value().get();
    }

};

} // namespace maybe
```

And here's a small test .cpp file to make sure the implementation works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

#include "maybe.hpp"

struct foo {
    int i;

    foo(int i_): i(i_) {}
    foo() {}

    void bar(int j) {
        std::cout << "Bar." << ' ' << i*j << std::endl;
    }

    ~foo() {
        std::cout << "Deleting a foo..." << std::endl;
    }
};

maybe::Maybe<char> letter(int i) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < 26)
        return maybe::Maybe<char>(i + 'A');
    return maybe::nothing;
}

int main() {

    maybe::Maybe<std::unique_ptr<foo>> i{ std::make_unique<foo>(8) };

    maybe::Maybe<std::unique_ptr<foo>> j = std::move(i);

    maybe::Maybe<foo> f{12321};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << j.hasValue() << ' ' << i.hasValue() << std::endl;

    f.apply(&foo::bar, 2);



    int p = 7;
    maybe::Maybe<int&> q = p;



    std::cout << q.value() << std::endl;

    p = 8;

    std::cout << q.value() << std::endl;

    // Could I possibly do something simpler like `q = 6`?
    q.value() = 6;

    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    q.apply([] (int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; });
    std::cout << q.apply([] (int a) { return a + 1; }).value();


    maybe::Maybe<char> c = letter(12);
    std::cout << c.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Is there anything that I seem to have messed up, or situations I've overlooked? I'm specifically concerned in making sure that the implementation is efficient, and has easy use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use `std::unique_ptr`. (It's much safer and easier than manual memory management).
- *bug:* The `delete` operator will call the object destructor. We should not call the destructor manually. (A perfect example of why we should use `std::unique_ptr` and avoid this entirely :D ).
- Note that `std::optional` doesn't allocate memory itself, but keeps the contained object on the stack. This could be done with a boolean flag and `std::aligned_storage` or perhaps with `std::variant`.
- `value` and `valueOr` can be `const` functions. `value` should perhaps return a reference, and have const and non-const versions.
- *opinion:* I really dislike that `std::optional` overloads `operator->` and `operator*`. They're unnecessary and make it less obvious what the type is. It's not a pointer type (at least semantically), so I don't think they make sense. Personally I'd skip them.
- If we're creating a special case for reference types, and hiding the `std::reference_wrapper` internally, we need to re-implement the other access functions, not just `value()`. Currently the `reference_wrapper` is exposed through `valueOr`, `operator*` and `operator->`.

  (This results in a subtly different implementation for "reference maybes", and I don't know if that's a good thing or not. However, I feel like we should either hide the `std::reference_wrapper` entirely, or let the user create a `Maybe<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` themselves if they need one).
- The `apply` methods are very interesting. :)

  - I think we need `const` versions (for calling `const` member functions of types contained in `const Maybe`'s).
  - Since the `Maybe` can also store simple POD types, where the `apply` functions do not make sense, perhaps `apply` should be implemented as a set of free functions (and named `invoke_maybe` or something similar). This would provide a calling syntax more consistent with `std::invoke` and `std::bind`. It would also allow `invoke_maybe` to be implemented for other classes, such as `std::function` (or `std::optional`), returning an empty `Maybe` if necessary.
  - *feature request:* Note that [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) lets us access member variables, not just member functions. This doesn't appear to be supported with the current `apply` implementation, but would be pretty cool.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll be making the changes you mentioned. A few questions though: 
1) Why is it bad to call the destructor manually? I understand it's better to use a unique_ptr overall, but why is it specifically a bug to call the destructor manually?
2) For the assignment operators, I tried using the copy-and-swap idiom. Does this only apply to copy-assignments? I thought it was supposed to implement both assignment operators, to simply the code. Am I correct, or did I use CAS wrong?

Comment: 1) Since `delete` calls the destructor itself, we end up with two destructor calls, which is undefined behaviour. (Everything in C++ depends on having one destructor call. Once that happens, the object lifetime is deemed to have ended.) 2) You're quite right. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

To be frank, I'm not sure it really is a `Maybe` implementation. It's actually not very different from a smart pointer (well, maybe not that smart since the destructor deletes the underlying value twice, as @user673679 points out :). By the way I don't think that a smart pointer -or any pointer- is a bad approximation of the Haskell `Maybe` type: it can be either `nullptr` (`Nothing`) or pointing to some value (`Just some_value`). Of course, `std::optional` would probably be more efficient, since it stores the optional value on the stack, but I don't believe it's a conceptual leap towards `Maybe` either: the real difference between pointers and `std::optional` on the one hand, and `Maybe` on the other hand is that `Maybe` is a sum type, that is a type that can be either one of different types, whereas pointers or `std::optional` are types with a well-defined null/void value.

Implementing sum types in C++ is rather difficult. The standard library's sum type -`std::variant`- is rather cumbersome and has drawn convincing [complaints](https://bitbashing.io/std-visit.html). But it's also a path to a lot more power than you could reach with pointers or optional: they can be a good approximation of `Maybe`, but not of `Either`, for instance, which isn't fundamentally different though, and a lot more powerful.

So what would `Maybe` as a sum type look like in C++? I would say something like:

```
#include <variant>

struct Nothing {};

template <typename T>
struct Just {
    Just(const T& t) : value(t) {}
    Just(T&& t) : value(t) {}
    Just() = default;

    T value;   
};

template <typename T>
using Maybe = std::variant<Nothing, Just<T>>;
```

So, how would you use it then? Creating one looks very much like what you did:

```
Maybe<char> letter(int i) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < 26) return Just<char>('A' + i);
    return Nothing();
}
```

Now, what can you do with it? `Maybe` is a functor in the Haskell sense, so you need a way to map a function onto it. The Haskell signature is : `(a -> b) -> F a -> F b`. The C++ implementation would be along the lines:

```
template <typename Fn, typename T>
auto fmap(Fn fn, const Maybe<T>& mb) {

    using return_type   = decltype(fn(std::declval<T>()));    

    auto visitor = [fn](auto&& arg) -> Maybe<return_type> 
    {
        using Type = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Type, Nothing>) return Nothing();
        else return Just<return_type>(fn(arg.value));
    };

    return std::visit(visitor, mb); 
      /* visit is the *apply* you're looking for: given a visitor with 
         overloads for any type the variant can contain a value of, it 
         will apply the correct overload on the value it contains */
}
```

Now Maybe is also a monad. If you want to implement the `>>=` (aka `bind`), whose signature in Haskell is `(a -> M b) -> M a -> M b`, it isn't very different:

```
template <typename Fn, typename T>
auto bind(Fn fn, const Maybe<T>& mb) {

    using return_type = decltype(fn(std::declval<T>()));    

    auto visitor = [fn](auto&& arg) -> return_type 
    {
        using Type = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Type, Nothing>) return Nothing();
        else return fn(arg.value);
    };

    return std::visit(visitor, mb);
}
```

Here's a [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P3lXkzuKq6FQs58C) to those few snippets of code if you feel like exploring that vein.